# Unable to resolve memory leak in CoreFoundation object

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-leaks, abaddressbook

I use the following code to remove all contacts I have inserted in the address book, depending on the `group` they have been added to :

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

NSArray* contactsArray = (__bridge NSArray *)(ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers([self ABGetAddressGroup:addressBook]));

if (contactsArray.count) {

    for (NSUInteger index = 0 ; index < contactsArray.count; index++) {

        ABRecordRef person = (__bridge ABRecordRef)(contactsArray[index]);

        ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(addressBook, person, NULL);
    }

    CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)contactsArray);

    NSArray *groups = (__bridge NSArray *) ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups(addressBook);

    for (id _group in groups) {

        NSString *currentGroupName = (__bridge NSString*) ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(_group), kABGroupNameProperty);

        if ([[self getDatabase] isEqualToString:currentGroupName]) {

            ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(addressBook, (__bridge ABRecordRef)(_group), NULL);
        }

        CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)(currentGroupName));
    }

    CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)(groups));
}

if (ABAddressBookHasUnsavedChanges(addressBook)) {//potential leak of an object stored in contactsArray

    //Save recent changes
    ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, NULL);

} else {

    NSLog(@"Nothing to do here, let's eat cake");
}

CFRelease(addressBook);
```

The Analyzer show a warning (if that's what it's called) in the `ABAddressBookHasUnsavedChanges`...`potential leak of an object stored in contactsArray`. What do I need to do to get rid of this?

If use `CFRelease` as follows:

```
CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)(contactsArray));
```

the analyzer says : `Reference-counted object is used after it is released`, even if it released at the end of the non-returning method, and the app crashes.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get rid of such memory leaks?

Comment: the _potential leak_ is (as its name says) potential only, which request extra attanention from developer; but that phrase does not mark leaks onminpotently.

Comment: Instruments shows actual leaks on these objects.

Comment: I've found your leak. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is in this line:

```
CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)contactsArray);
```

because this line runs **only** when the `if` statement's true-branch is executed, therefore nothing releases the `contactsArray`  in every other scenarios. that is *pure* a leak here.

luckily, there are two ways to solve such simple problem.

**Option #1**

passing the ownership to `ARC`:

```
NSArray* contactsArray = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)(ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers([self ABGetAddressGroup:addressBook]));

if (contactsArray.count) {
     // (...)

     // CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)contactsArray);

     // (...)
}
```

**Option #2**

making sure to release the object in any case:

```
NSArray* contactsArray = (__bridge NSArray *)(ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers([self ABGetAddressGroup:addressBook]));

if (contactsArray.count) {
     // (...)

     // CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)contactsArray);

     // (...)
}

if (contactsArray) CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)contactsArray);
```

something like this could help on you, I guess.

Comment: The `CFRelease()` was placed inside `if` to avoid `NULL` releases, which would cause app crashes. Option #1 was enough. Letting ARC take over seems to be working. Thank you.